# How can I find if a set of 5 numbers add up to 15 in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

An assignment in my computing class is to find if any numbers from a set of 5 add up to 15, if they do award a point. I cannot figure out how to find if multiple specific numbers can be made from adding up a random set of 5 numbers. Are they any algorithms specific to this? Also it has to be written in visual basic.

Comment: The sentence up to "from a set of 5 add up to 15" makes sense, but what do you mean with "if they do award a point?". Also I don't understand the sentence where you want to "make" specific numbers "from adding up" something. Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: You will need to use some ifs and some loops, probably nested. Start with the first number, and end with the last.

Comment: I meant for every possible set of numbers it can use to add up to 15, its registered and a number is added to a variable for example: intpoints

Comment: I still don't get it. What is you initial data (input) and what is your desired output?

Comment: the input is 5 randomly generated numbers between 1 and 10, I then need to find how many sets of these numbers add up to 15 and output this

Comment: OK, that's clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you are looking for is called [BackTracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). Since this is homework, I will not bother to provide code. The idea is this.

- Take numbers recursively as long as their sum is less than 15
- if it gets exactly 15 then OK, you found the solution
- if it exceeds 15, then return to one step back and take another number
- continue until all variants are done

Comment: This is, of course, if all numbers are positive. Otherwise you must do a brute-force all-variants search

Answer (score 0):

In the case of 5 numbers I would just brute force it and try all 32 possible combinations.

Here is some possible pseudo code for this task:

```
input = Array of 5 random integers (starting with index 0)
onoff = new Array of 5 integers (starting with index 0), initialized to 0

loop
  // Create all possible combinations of 0 and 1 in onoff Array
  // Hint: This is the same as counting up a binary number and looking at the bits.
  onoff[0] = onoff[0]+1
  for i=0 to 3
    if onoff[i] > 1
      onoff[i] = 0
      onoff[i+1] = onoff[i+1] + 1

  if onoff[4] > 1
    break loop

  // Create sum for given combination
  sum = 0
  for i=0 to 4
    sum = sum + onoff[i]*input[i]

  if sum = 15
    output "Found value set"
    for i=0 to 4
      if onoff[i] = 1
        output " "+input[i]
```

Translation into VB is still homework :-)